# How can I build AOSP (Marshmallow) efficiently?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, android-build

When building Lollipop, I could compile my changes by running:

```
make clean-framework clean-services clean-services.core services.core services framework && make snod
```

However, this is not reliable for Marshmallow. Sometimes it works, and other times my changes will not be compiled. I have also seen this produce an unbootable build, forcing me to do a full `make -j8`, which takes almost an hour on my machine.

Am I missing a new build target? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have USE_CCACHE setup properly?  When I make a nominal change and run "make -jN" it will often compile Marshmallow in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Chris yes, I have `export USE_CCACHE=1` in my `.bashrc`, and have confirmed that it is working.

Comment: You're probably missing some dependency.
Do the following, compare the img files after a full build vs partial so you can understand where you're missing out.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira thanks for the advice, but I've already solved this issue. I'll post my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my partial builds failed to boot was due to `dex pre-optimization`. When dexpreopt is enabled, you cannot recompile certain parts of the system image, since they are byte-aligned and optimized together at compile time. After disabling dexpreopt, and doing a `make clobber && make -j6`, I was able to do partial builds with no issues.

To disable dexpreopt, set the following variables in your terminal:

```
export WITH_DEXPREOPT=false
export DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true
```

TIP: add the above to your `build/envsetup.sh` or your `.bashrc` so you don't have to remember each time.

TIP 2: There is also a `DONT_DEXPREOPT_PREBUILTS`, but I have never had a problem with that, so I leave it set to the default, which is`false`. If you set this variable to `true`, it will take an incredibly long time (easily over an hour) for the device to boot after your flash it, since it has to optimize everything first.